# Python requests.get() seems to only be retrieving Source Code, not the HTML visible on the website

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am trying to scrape pinnacle.com to extract player prop odds into a dataframe that lists the player name, type of bet (points, rebounds, etc.), over odds, and under odds.

I am having trouble accessing the body of the given url that has the span classes that hold all that type of information I need for my dataframe. This is my current code that accesses the url, which seems to only be getting the source code. When I try to find all the  tags or  tags, nothing seems to be returned.

I have been trying to check for the tags I am looking for using the final print statement, and it is returning "None". I have compared the response to the inspect element raw data, and it does not match so I am not sure where I am going wrong.

This is my current code. Any help would be appreciated immensely.

```
url = "https://www.pinnacle.com/en/basketball/nba/los-angeles-lakers-vs-orlando-magic/1564389023#player-props"

# Make a GET request to the webpage
response = requests.get(url)
content = response.text

# Parse the HTML content
soup = BeautifulSoup(content, "html.parser")
print(soup.span)
```

Comment: Probably because its dynamically generated with javascript, if that's the case you should use selenium instead

Comment: Also you could open the developer tools "F12 -> Network" and check if it uses some kind of API, it would be harder to make the scraper, but the most efficient way

Comment: If you use the Network tab in the Dev Tools, you'll see that a lot of the data on the site is fetched asynchronously with JavaScript after the skeleton of the site has loaded. You can also tell that by the slight delay between when the structure loads and the data appears. You'll need something like Selenium to fetch that, or contact their API directly.

Comment: Thanks so much guys. I am now using selenium and finding it a lot easier. Cheers!

Comment: *"Python requests.get() seems to only be retrieving Source Code, not the HTML visible on the website"* - that's what `requests.get` does [at most - sometimes there are errors and then you get nothing]